# Plot gradient heatmap circles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts, heatmap

In R, using `ggplot`, I have this `geom_count` graph:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)

theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_count(col="tomato3", show.legend=F) + labs(y="hwy", x="cty")
```

Which generates the following plot:

[image]

However I would like to generate gradient circles instead of solid color circles. Pretty much like this unrelated image:

[image]

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired plot you show sounds more like you want a 2D density. You can create that with

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_density_2d_filled() + 
  labs(y="hwy", x="cty")
```

But if you really wanted to just color your points, you could use the `stat(n)` calcualted by `geom_count`

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_count(aes(color=stat(n)), show.legend=F) + 
  labs(y="hwy", x="cty") + 
  scale_color_continuous(type="viridis")
```